# How to use FM Radio on SIM808 EVB-V3.2.2

Tags: arduino, at-command

I Just bought the SIM808 GSM/GPRS/GPS shield with an arduino Mega 2560. I have written a simple sketch
shown below which I'm using to execute AT commands on my SIM808 shield.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX

void setup()  
{
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() // run over and over
{
  if (mySerial.available())
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());

  if (Serial.available())
  {
    while(Serial.available())
    {
      mySerial.write(Serial.read());
    }
    mySerial.println();
  }
}
```

I keep getting ERROR as a result of executing the AT+FMOPEN=1 command which is used to initialize the FM Radio integrated with the module. So far, all other AT commands works great except this one.

[image]

My SIM808 Module looks like this:
[image]

Comment: What is the output of the following command `AT+FMOPEN?`

Comment: @StefanBossbaly, **AT+FMOPEN?** Still returns **ERROR**

Answer (score 0):

The FM Feature is only available on the SIM800, SIM800L,or SIM800H.
Sadly the SIM808 does not have the FM Radio feature according to the datasheets.

https://datasheetspdf.com/datasheet/SIM800.html

https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf/840127/SIMCom/SIM808/1